# How to set values of a Pyomo indexed variable only for some indexes and let the others free?

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm currently constracting an optimization model and I have a question regarding setting predefined/fixed parameter values.

My parameter is indexed by two different predifined sets G & T something like the below:
'''model.q=param(G,T)'''

My question has to do with the below:

I want to set predefined values to SOME of the indexed values of this parameter and let the other free for the problem to be decided:
For example q[1,"A"]=50 or q[2,"B"]=80 but not to all of them.

For this purpose i have created an appropriate dictionary with the form of {(G,T) : x } for specific G and T values but when I'm trying to initialize the parameter with this dictionary I get an error that the parameter value is missing for some indexes which is correct as the dictionary refers to specific values.

Is there another approach for the above?

Would it work if i set constraints to the parameter in the optimization model with the dictionary's specific values for the specific indexes in order for all the othe indexed values of the parameter  to be free to be decided by the model?

P.S.: I know that I haven't attached any code but even the specific block is too big to attach and I hope my writing is explanatory enough!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.  First off, vocabulary... If the "item" can change during the solve, it is a *variable*.  *Parameters* are fixed constants in the model.  So, if I understand you correctly, you have an indexed variable and you would like to assign values and lock them in.  You could either set the values and then separately set the lock to True or do it "all in one" with `fix()`.  In the model below, `x['A']` and `x['C']` are fixed and the other values may float:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

locks = {"A": 12, "C": 14}

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=list('ABCD'))

m.x = pyo.Var(m.S, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

# set and lock the vars...

for idx in locks.keys():
    m.x[idx].fix(locks[idx])

m.pprint()
```

##### Output:

```
1 Set Declarations
    S : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    4 : {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=4, Index=S
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          A :     0 :    12 :  None :  True : False : NonNegativeReals
          B :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          C :     0 :    14 :  None :  True : False : NonNegativeReals
          D :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

2 Declarations: S x
```

This has some duplicate information:  [How can I set a value of an indexed variable? - Pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442540/how-can-i-set-a-value-of-an-indexed-variable-pyomo)